# Light deflection by inhomogeneous electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, resource-recommendations

This is a screenshot of the Noble Prize organization website on the biography of the Noble laureate Johannes Stark. And this is what I found worthy to ask about his work. In the last lines of his biography it mentions something about his research on the deflection of light due to strong inhomogeneous electric fields. I found this years ago, I searched throughout the internet, but I couldn't find anything about it, not even in the fringe science or obsolete theories topics. I wonder if you know something about light deflection by strong inhomogeneous electric or magnetic fields, and if you do, could you please provide some bibliographical references?

https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1919/stark/biographical/

[image]

Comment: From Wikipedia: "A supporter of Adolf Hitler from 1924, Stark was one of the main figures, along with fellow Nobel laureate Philipp Lenard, in the anti-Semitic Deutsche Physik movement,"

Comment: I am well aware of that, the same thing says the Nobel Prize organization website as an introduction to his biography. Nevertheless there is something called "the Stark effect" which is the equivalent of the Zeeman effect with the electric field. He made important contribution to physics. Werner Von Braun also should have been a Nazi supporter, to be the the chief designer of the German V1 and V2 rockets. Nevertheless Von Braun got a well paid job as the first NASA director, after the war. But let the politics aside. Is light deviation due the inhomogeneous electric field a real thing or not?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you cannot find it because the original publications were in German journals, thus they are either unavailable in English or have not been properly translated.

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/andp.19484370506

First paragraph of the correspondence:

> J. Stark hat im ('Herbst 1946'), sowie ausführlicher im Herbst 1947 private Mitteilungen über verschiedene Effekte veröffentlicht, nach denen ein Strahl von polarisiertem Licht durch ein inhomogenes elektrisches Feld beeinflußt werden soll, falls die elektrischen Vektoren von Licht  und Feld  parallel liegen.

Roughly: J. Stark had published in private communications in the Fall of 1946 and detailed in Fall of 1947 about different effects, whereas a beam of polarized licht through an inhomogeneous electric field would be influenced, if the electric vectors of the light and the field are parallel.

It seems, from the description you provide, that Kunze and Hohl did to replicate the reported phenomenon, but due to restrictions in their setup it was impossible to replicate as initially stated by Stark.

Them being private communications, it is very likely there were never proper publications about the topic and since the experiment was not successful it was never properly followed up.

---

As requested by the original poster, here are a few interesting examples of metameterials where you can change the propagation direction of a light beam, mostly in materials which are specifically engineered for that purpose. Pure electromagnetic light steering is, as far as my understanding goes, not a topic that has been actively investigated in recent years.

https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04210 Article by Vlasov, et. Al. where light is steered by creating photonic crystals

https://www.comsol.com/blogs/engineering-the-flow-of-light-using-photonic-crystals/ nice article from COMSOL on how to achieve such structures through simulations

https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2007.28 Cai et. Al. achieved light steering by engineering structural properties

Comment: Ok. Is light deflection due to unhomogeneous electric field a real thing? If so, then it could provide an alternative explanation for the light deflection of a star by the gravity of the Sun.

Comment: @EduardOganesian The light deflection occurs only in an optical material. It does not occur in vacuum, so "it's not a real thing" the way you are asking. It's an effect of the interaction of electromagnetic fields with matter.

Comment: What would be an example of it? For instance, does light deflect in glass when an electric field is applied perpendicular to the direction of propagation?

Comment: @EduardOganesian I modified my answer with some resources on metamaterials which are specifically engineered to steer light by changing the nanostructure of materials. About materials which act upon an external electric field applied, look into non-linear optics (specifically, electro-optic effect or Kerr effect). Further information goes well outside the scope of the original question but you are welcome to start a new question about non-linear optics.

Comment: @ondas Thank you for your search. Does light deflection in photonic crystals involve inhomogeneous electric fields?

Comment: @EduardOganesian Not directly from the resources I provided. Here is a study of photonic crystals modified with external electric fields: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0030402622012451 nonetheless inhomogeneous electric fields are very rare under controlled lab conditions (e.g. applying voltage between two plates e.g. condensers) and that goes well beyond my area of expertise, sorry I cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time ever I answer a question in Stack Exchange, and it happens to be to my own question. If this claim is not a quackery, which I believe it's not, then it necessarily must have something to do with the Kerr effect. First lets review the Kerr effect, it is essentially the modification of the refraction index of a material due to an applied electric field. From this it's very easy to understand the light deviation in a material where an inhomogeneous electric field is applied, thus a material whose refraction index is not homogeneous. This is a start for the explanation.

[image: This is]

This is an image taken form a youtube channel where the author shows light bending in a medium whose refraction index gradually increaces from the top to the bottom.

And this is a paper, accepted for publication in Physical Review A, about the optical Kerr effect in vacuum. You can draw you own conclusions.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00896